# How to view linux file using the "tail" command from Oracle Forms

Tags: linux, oracle, oracleforms, tail

I would like to view, from Oracle Forms, a linux file 
using the "tail" command.
I need to monitor and display the new events and information
in a system log in real time, opening it - for example - in 
an editor of Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on Oracle Forms version.

- if it is 6i or lower (read: client-server architecture), you'd use `host` built-in to run operating system commands
- if it is 9i or higher (read: applications are deployed on web), you'd need to install `webutil` and use `client_host`

---

However, why do you involve Oracle (a relational **database** management system) into something related to **operating system**? Can't you use a more appropriate tool for that?

Comment: To be fair, Oracle Forms is for building UIs and it's not unreasonable to want to blend data from the database with data from other non-db sources in the one interface.

Comment: I develop applications web-based, using Oracle Forms 11 and 12c.
The application server is on linux system, so the logs that I need 
to show - from my applications - are on linux.

Thank for your suggestion, I'll try webutil - client_host.